# WSO2 am - generate key for application

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I tried to call API from wso2 to create an application and generate applications key. I call API `{{storeURL}}/api/am/store/v0.12/applications` for create application. This API is OK.

Then I called api `{{storeURL}}/api/am/store/v0.12/applications/generate-keys?applicationId={{applicationId}}` and I saw this error (I have `wso2am-2.2.0`):

```
> ERROR GlobalThrowableMapper An Unknown exception has been captured by
> global exception mapper. java.lang.NullPointerException   at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getApplicationByUUID_aroundBody242(ApiMgtDAO.java:5550)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getApplicationByUUID(ApiMgtDAO.java:5517)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.getApplicationByUUID_aroundBody114(AbstractAPIManager.java:1593)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.getApplicationByUUID(AbstractAPIManager.java:1592)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:194)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.ApplicationsApi.applicationsGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApi.java:178)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
>   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:192)
>   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
>   at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)     at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Was that a POST request with a json body like `{
  "validityTime": "3600",
  "keyType": "PRODUCTION",
  "accessAllowDomains": ["ALL"
  ]
}` ?

Comment: yes{
  "validityTime": "3600",
  "keyType": "PRODUCTION",
  "accessAllowDomains": ["ALL"]
}

Comment: have you added the scope of generation-keys into your very first authentication create request ?

Comment: i called this url 
1. {{gatewayURL}}/token
2. {{storeURL}}/api/am/store/v0.12/applications
{
    "name": "test",
    "throttlingTier": "Unlimited",
    "description": null,
    "subscriber": "{{username}}"
  
}

3.{{storeURL}}/api/am/store/v0.12/applications/generate-keys?applicationId={{applicationId}}
{
  "validityTime": "3600",
  "keyType": "PRODUCTION",
  "accessAllowDomains": ["ALL"]
}

Comment: I just tried this in a newly downloaded 2.2.0 pack and it works fine. What are the configuration changes you have done in the `api-manager.xml` file? Can you provide a complete request-response list since your Token call?

Comment: this is from api-manager.xml but if i use differentapi from wso2  - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/store/ i think
<ETagSkipURI>
                <URI>/api/am/store/{version}/applications/generate-keys</URI>
                <HTTPMethods>POST</HTTPMethods>
            </ETagSkipURI>